# MongoDB script doesn't seem to execute properly but no error code or exit code

Tags: mongodb, exit, google-geocoder

I am a beginner and will try to explain my question as thoroughly as possible, but thank you in advance for your patience.

I am trying to run a script in MongoDB.  The script is using Google Geocoding to update Twitter records.  When I run the script, I get a message saying (in short) the code will exit when I have reached my daily limit of 2500 records.

My question is: how do I know when the code has exited and, also, if the script executed successfully?

Nothing seems to be happening but I am not getting an error of any kind.  Additionally, when I check the log file, it appears to be blank.  I have tried to search this several different ways but I'm not sure I'm using the proper lexicon as I am new to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's all about the specifics of the script. Are you talking about a mongodb shell script or something else? Basically, you need to add a lot more details.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm using a terminal set up on a VM provided by my professor. From the terminal, I executed a command to import a tsv file into mongodb. Then, I ran a command to add Google geocoding to the imported records. Nothing really happened. I received a message that the code would exit when finished and then the $ prompt came back but the log file is empty. 

I feel like I'm missing some fundamentals on how these systems work. If you could suggest a resource that would teach me more on this subject, I would really appreciate it. I really want to understand what's going on.

Comment: Start here to get oriented on MongoDB and how you can interact with it through the MongoDB shell to see if your data imported and updated correctly. https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/